# Highcharts 5 data-labels width in CSS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When highcharts is styled by javascript you can set the width of the dataLabels like so.

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    width:"2px"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7w1cr9j/

How would you do this in highcharts 5 when being styled by css as the style object no longer works.

Styled by CSS fiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/kpmsxycs/

Reason for needing to set the width is so that the dataLabels are wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in the older version of highcharts they would look at the style and generate the svg based on that, the reason it was splitting the text was because each word inside the `<text>` element was wrapped in a `<tspan>` element.

The only way I could get the desired results using CSS /Highcharts 5 was to use the option `useHTML` which basically puts a layer of HTML over the SVG. [Note that this can cause errors when exporting charts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html).

**Now down to the actual code.**

Replace you `plotOptions` to be this

```
pie: {
  allowPointSelect: true,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
    useHTML: true
  }
}
```

and add this class into your css

```
.highcharts-data-label span {
  word-wrap:break-word;
  white-space:pre-wrap!important;
}
```

[JSFiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/zr1b2uz6/1/)

Now you can have your pie *and* eat it too!